# Does The Windows Phone 7 Emulator Show A Watermark?

Tags: silverlight, windows-7, windows-phone-7

Does the Windows Phone 7 emulator show a watermark along the upper right edge of the display?

At first I thought it might be nested grids not overlapping properly and creating a thin vertical column of visual garbage in the upper right. But after creating a new project and zooming in on both garbage areas it turns out they are numbers.

Existing project: `"000 000 000006 001 000 00.0000"`
New, empty project: `"000 000 003296 002 001 00.0967"`

What are these? Any way to disable their visibility?

Answer (score 14):

These are frame rate counters used for measuring performance. Details here.

[Jeff Wilcox – Frame rate counters in Windows Phone](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/07/counters/)

The post also shows how to disable their display.

Answer (score 3):

In the App constructor in App.xaml.cs is generated code. Comment out these lines, like so:

```
public App()
{
  UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;

  // Uncomment to show graphics profiling information while debugging.
  if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
  {
    // Display the current frame rate counters.
    //Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;

    // Show the areas of the app that are being redrawn in each frame.
    //Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableRedrawRegions = true;

    // Enable non-production analysis visualization mode, 
    // which shows areas of a page that are being GPU accelerated with a colored overlay.
    //Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableCacheVisualization = true;
  }
```